# url for audioInputStream seems empty

Tags: java, file, audio

I am trying the following code to play an mp3. The file is in the correct folder. An exception is thrown when opening the file.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

When trying to print the url on the third line it gives me a null pointer exception.

I am compiling with 1.8 to a min compat version of 1.6. Could this be related?

```
    AudioInputStream audioIn = null;
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("./data/1.wav");
    System.out.print(url.getFile());

    try {
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        //audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(soundFile));

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {System.out.print("exception opening file");}
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        System.out.print("exception mediaplayer");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I had to put the data folder in the src directory.

Still a problem though: when I compile as a jar file, it does not find the data folder. And I want the user to be able to put different things in there.

Comment: Just to be clear. I want the user to be able to manually handle the files in src, "outside" of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a String var, you could use a Clip object. With Clip, it worked for me.

Comment: I am using clip, no? What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

A URL can see into Jar, unlike a File address. So, you should be fine using the URL to obtain the file.

Two possible problems:

(1) if the file is an .mp3 and you are trying to load a .wav, there will of course be a mismatch as 1.mp3 <> 1.wav.

(2) putting the data into the src folder is not enough. It must also be in a subfolder of the folder that contains the "this" that you refer to. For example, if your code is in package "foo", the place to put the file would be src/foo/data/1.wav.

Do you have a library to decode the .mp3? If so, something like JavaZoom should work.

Comment: But I want to mp3 file outside of the jar, so the user can change it. Since I'm working with A LOT of mp3 files, it would be a nuissance to be able to send such a big jar back and forward to the users.

Comment: If the file is outside of the jar, and you want to get to it via a relative address, you'll have to use some combination of ".." to go up levels to parent folders, or use an absolute address. If you aren't hard-coding (don't know in advance) the files, then a JFileChooser might be helpful.

Comment: I never got that working. And I read that for security, java does not allow this.

Comment: Yes, security is an issue for Applets. Are you running this as an applet? But there are provisions for reading external files from within applications. Do you need links for the latter?